# Symfony 4 LDAP authentication

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I am currently trying to implement an LDAP authentication using the Symfony built-in module. 
I followed this tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html

But I can't make it work, and most of the research I have made concern Symfony 2.8 and none of this worked.

Here are my settings:

**config/services.yaml**

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']

Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: ######
            port: 389
            encryption: tls
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

**config/packages/security.yaml**

```
providers:
        app_users:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'DC=company,DC=com'
                search_dn: 'CN=######,DC=company,DC=com'
                search_password: '#######'
                uid_key: 'sAMAccountName'
                filter: '({uid_key}={username})'
                default_roles: 'ROLE_USER'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: false

            http_basic_ldap:
                provider: app_users
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: '{username}'
```

currently with this configuration I do have this error:

> Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error

I found no workarround yet, so I tried to replace TLS by SSL in the services.yaml file (I think it does not do anything by the way).

With the SSL argument it loop me to connect.

I also use the PHP function ldap_connect() to make sure my LDAP server works and it does.

If any one has any ideas?

EDIT: using SSL the log file returns always the same issue (the credentials are correct)

```
[2018-01-04 13:30:36] security.INFO: Basic authentication Authorization header found for user. {"username":"#######"} []
[2018-01-04 13:30:36] php.DEBUG: Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server ...
[2018-01-04 13:30:36] security.INFO: Basic authentication failed for user. {"username":"#######","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. : User \"######\" not found. : Can't contact LDAP server
```

Happy new year and thanks in advance.
AM.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I just removed the encryption: tls from the arguments of "Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\Ext Ldap\Adapter",

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ;

```
encryption: tls
```

from services.yaml